# Get the dropdown selected value in flask

Tags: javascript, python, jquery, ajax, leaflet

I am doing a project for the university, where I have made a dropdown menu in which the names of all the ships appear. In the menu I want to select a shipname, that "shipname" goes to the flask app and put it in selected_data. Also, when selecting the ship name, it should refresh the page with the new data automatically. I do not know how to continue, I would appreciate if someone could help me.

Dropdown menu options:

```
shipnames = s_copy['shipname'].unique()
selected_data = s_copy.loc[s_copy['shipname'] == request.form.get("shipname")] //(this code selects from my database the rows where the shipname == selected shipname html)
```

[image]

HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>Servidor Web Datos AIS FNB</title>
    </head>
<body>
<select name="shipname" method="POST" action="/">
  <option value="{{shipnames[0]}}" selected>{{shipnames[0]}}</option>
  {% for shipname in shipnames[1:] %}
  <option value="{{shipname}}">{{shipname}}</option>
  {% endfor %}
</select>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Buscar</button>
</select>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Nothing goes to Flask because you haven't created a `<form>` or anything else that actually sends the selection back to the server

Comment: Unless I'm mistaken with HTML - `<select name="shipname" method="POST" action="/">` is just a mangled attempt at getting a `form` and a `select`